# Как складывать числа с очень малой дробной частью?

Tags: python, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Скажите, как складывать числа с очень малой дробной частью и сохранять их в переменой.
Например, у меня переменная `num` содержит значение - 0.00000000.
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы она могла увеличиваться, например, на + 0.00000100 , когда пользователь вводит команду "тест"

Если запустить этот код и вписать "тест", то код выведет "1e-06"

```
num = 0.00000000

word = input()
if word == "тест":
        num = num + 0.00000100
        print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае следует использовать форматированный вывод с указанием требуемого числа знаков `'{:.6f}'` после десятичной запятой/точки:

```py
for i in range(0, 12):
    num = num + 0.00000100
    print('{:.6f}'.format(num))
```

```
0.000001
0.000002
0.000003
0.000004
0.000005
0.000006
0.000007
0.000008
0.000009
0.000010
0.000011
0.000012
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете указать формат вывода числа с помощью функции format. Например, чтобы вывести число с точностью до 10 знаков после запятой, вы можете использовать следующую строку:

```
print(format(num, '.10f'))
```

В этом случае результат будет выглядеть так: 0.0000010000. Также вы можете использовать этот формат, чтобы отобразить число в другом формате, например, с округлением до целых чисел.

Также стоит обратить внимание, что числа с плавающей точкой могут не точно представлять действительные числа, поэтому может понадобиться использовать другой тип данных, например, decimal, чтобы сохранить точность.

Когда число с плавающей точкой слишком малое или слишком большое, оно обычно представляется в экспоненциальной форме. Например, число 1e-06 означает 1 * 10^(-6), то есть 0.000001.

Вот пример кода, который демонстрирует, как вы можете использовать функцию format для вывода числа с точностью до 10 знаков после запятой:

```
num = 0.00000000

def add(num, value):
    num = num + value
    return format(num, '.10f')

num = add(num, 0.00000100)
print(num)
num = add(num, 0.00000100)
print(num)
```

Результатом выполнения этого кода будет:

```
0.0000010000
0.0000020000
```